# Best practice to look up Java Enum

Tags: java, enums

We have a REST API where clients can supply parameters representing values defined on the server in Java Enums.

So we can provide a descriptive error, we add this `lookup` method to each Enum.  Seems like we're just copying code (bad).  Is there a better practice?

```
public enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C, D;

    public static MyEnum lookup(String id) {
        try {
            return MyEnum.valueOf(id);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Invalid value for my enum blah blah: " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: The default error message provided by `valueOf(..)` would be `No enum const class a.b.c.MyEnum.BadValue`.  I would like to provide a more descriptive error from the API.

Comment: Well, there's nothing wrong with the IllegalArgumentException, which is already a RuntimeException. What do you want to improve here ?

Comment: Add a more descriptive message than that provided when just using `valueOf` (and `IllegalArgumentException`)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Probably you can implement generic static `lookup` method.

Like so

```
public class LookupUtil {
   public static <E extends Enum<E>> E lookup(Class<E> e, String id) {   
      try {          
         E result = Enum.valueOf(e, id);
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
         // log error or something here

         throw new RuntimeException(
           "Invalid value for enum " + e.getSimpleName() + ": " + id);
      }

      return result;
   }
}
```

Then you can

```
public enum MyEnum {
   static public MyEnum lookup(String id) {
       return LookupUtil.lookup(MyEnum.class, id);
   }
}
```

or call explicitly utility class lookup method.

Comment: You can't create a base enum to extend child enums, as "All enums implicitly extend java.lang.Enum. Since Java does not support multiple inheritance, an enum cannot extend anything else", so there's nowhere to put this code, unless you want to put it in some sort of static utility class and call it with the enum class parameter.

Comment: What advantage does your utility method give over just invoking Enum.valueOf?

Comment: Post and pre actions and error handling. As I understand it is Error handling which is copy and pasted across different enum types.

Comment: Another extension would be to create an annotation that injects this method into any enum marked with that annotation (using Spring, AspectJ, etc).

Comment: Thanks @Mykola. What if I want to print something like "The allowed values are:" with the string values from my enum? How can I do it?

Comment: Still don't see why you'd do this. You're wrapping `IllegalArgumentException` in a runtime exception thrown by a utility class...for what gain? The default exception thrown by the `valueOf()` implementation in Enum is sufficient: it gives the invalid type i.e. input as part of the exception's message.

Comment: @atc because you could log it to a database or something if you want, so that developers know something's wrong (see `// log error or something here`)

Comment: Why are you throwing a new `RuntimeException` instead of an `IllegalArgumentException`? The latter seems more appropriate to me (and apparently to the designers of `valueOf` because that's what they use).

Comment: Also instead of calling `Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, id)` you could simply call `MyEnum.valueOf(id)`. Since `IllegalArgumentException` is more appropriate than `RuntimeException` there is no need for that utility method at all.

Comment: Nit-picky, but why not   try { return Enum.valueOf(e, id); } ...   ?   putting the return at the end forces the dev to scan farther in the method.

Answer (score 13):

Looks like you have a bad practice here but not where you think.

Catching an `IllegalArgumentException` to rethrow another `RuntimeException` with a clearer message might look like a good idea but it is not. Because it means you care about messages in your exceptions.

If you care about messages in your exceptions, then it means that your user is somehow seeing your exceptions. This is bad.

If you want to provide an explicit error message to your user, you should check the validity of the enum value when parsing user input and send the appropriate error message in the response if user input is incorrect.

Something like:

```
// This code uses pure fantasy, you are warned!
class MyApi
{
    // Return the 24-hour from a 12-hour and AM/PM

    void getHour24(Request request, Response response)
    {
        // validate user input
        int nTime12 = 1;
        try
        {
            nTime12 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParam("hour12"));
            if( nTime12 <= 0 || nTime12 > 12 )
            {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }
        }
        catch( NumberFormatException e )
        {
            response.setCode(400); // Bad request
            response.setContent("time12 must be an integer between 1 and 12");
            return;
        }

        AMPM pm = null;
        try
        {
            pm = AMPM.lookup(request.getParam("pm"));
        }
        catch( IllegalArgumentException e )
        {
            response.setCode(400); // Bad request
            response.setContent("pm must be one of " + AMPM.values());
            return;
        }

        response.setCode(200);
        switch( pm )
        {
            case AM:
                response.setContent(nTime12);
                break;
            case PM:
                response.setContent(nTime12 + 12);
                break;
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in essence we do what you're suggesting.  We throw the exception, then a class higher on the stack catches it, then returns just the exception message to the client through the REST API (in a defined error response)

Comment: What I suggested is that you should not catch generic exceptions to return their message, but return the message meant to explain why the exception was catched. Having a generic error response based on your exceptions is a leak of the internal architecture to the client and is a bad practice. The error message of your API should not depend on the error reporting architecture of the implementation (in this case, Java exceptions).

Answer (score 11):

We do all our enums like this when it comes to Rest/Json etc.
It has the advantage that the error is human readable and also gives you the accepted value list. We are using a custom method MyEnum.fromString instead of MyEnum.valueOf, hope it helps.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A, B, C, D;

    private static final Map<String, MyEnum> NAME_MAP = Stream.of(values())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(MyEnum::toString, Function.identity()));

    public static MyEnum fromString(final String name) {
        MyEnum myEnum = NAME_MAP.get(name);
        if (null == myEnum) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("'%s' has no corresponding value. Accepted values: %s", name, Arrays.asList(values())));
        }
        return myEnum;
    }
}
```

so for example if you call

```
MyEnum value = MyEnum.fromString("X");
```

you'll get an IllegalArgumentException with the following message:

> 'X' has no corresponding value. Accepted values: [A, B, C, D]

you can change the IllegalArgumentException to a custom one.

Answer (score 7):

Guava also provides such function which will return an `Optional` if an enum cannot be found.

```
Enums.getIfPresent(MyEnum.class, id).toJavaUtil()
            .orElseThrow(()-> new RuntimeException("Invalid enum blah blah blah.....")))
```

Answer (score 6):

Apache Commons Lang 3 contais the class EnumUtils. If you aren't using Apache Commons in your projects, you're doing it wrong. You are reinventing the wheel!

There's a dozen of cool methods that we could use without throws an Exception. For example:

> Gets the enum for the class, returning null if not found.
>
> This method differs from Enum.valueOf in that it does not throw an
>   exceptionfor an invalid enum name and performs case insensitive
>   matching of the name.

```
EnumUtils.getEnumIgnoreCase(SeasonEnum.class, season);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want the lookup to be case insensitive you can loop through the values making it a little more friendly:

```
 public enum MyEnum {
   A, B, C, D;

      public static MyEnum lookup(final String id) {
        for(MyEnum enumValue: values()){
           if(enumValue.name().equalsIgnoreCase(id)){
              return enumValue;
           }
        }  
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid value for my enum: " + id);
       }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, not really what I was looking for, but a good idea.  Note in your `lookup` you're not actually returning any value from the method.

Comment: Good point. Should be :
if(enum.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(id)) return enum;
You could then eliminate the boolean and just throw the exception if you get past the loop.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `enum.name()` instead of `enum.toString()` since `toString` method might be overridden and return some kind of human-readable description instead of name of the enum constant.

Answer (score 3):

Why do we have to write that 5 line code ?

```
public class EnumTest {
public enum MyEnum {
    A, B, C, D;
}

@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    MyEnum.valueOf("A"); //gives you A
    //this throws ILlegalargument without having to do any lookup
    MyEnum.valueOf("RADD"); 
}
}
```

Comment: The idea/requirement is to re-throw special exception

Comment: That's right.  See updated post for a little more description on the "default" error vs. a more descriptive error.

Comment: In that case the answer from @"Mykola Golubyev" should have solved your problem that is a static lookup utility class and you can throw any message/exception you want in the catch block ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message in IllegalArgumentException is already descriptive enough.

Your method makes a generic exception out of a specific one with the same message simply reworded.  A developer would prefer the specific exception type and can handle the case appropriately instead of trying to handle RuntimeException.

If the intent is to make the message more user friendly, then references to values of enums is irrelevant to them anyway.  Let the UI code determine what should be displayed to the user, and the UI developer would be better off with the IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: The "default" error message would be: `No enum const class a.b.c.MyEnum.BadValue`.  I would prefer to return a more relevant error message from the REST API.  The developer creating the front end won't really know what to do with the default error other than just display it - which is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: I fail to see how your example message is any better.  Neither is appropriate for a user so the exception should be handled and a proper user facing message displayed.  This is different then placing the message in the exception, which should be for the developer.

Answer (score 2):

update: As GreenTurtle correctly remarked, the following is wrong

---

I would just write

```
boolean result = Arrays.asList(FooEnum.values()).contains("Foo");
```

This is possibly less performant than catching a runtime exception, but makes for much cleaner code. Catching such exceptions is always a bad idea, since it is prone to misdiagnosis.
What happens when the retrieval of the compared value itself causes an IllegalArgumentException ? This would then be treaten like a non matching value for the enumerator.

Comment: This code will never return true unless you implement in your FooEnum class an equals method that can handle String objects. This happens because the generated ArrayList contains objects of type FooEnum and will always return false if contains is requested with a String object.

Comment: @GreenTurtle Yes you are obviously right, forgot that the Enum#equals only works with object compare. For enums, you shouldn't even be able to implement your own equals.
I would still try to avoid catching generic runtime exceptions though and just iterate through it, doing a string compare.

Comment: boolean result = Arrays.stream(FooEnum.values()).map(Enum::name).collect(Collectors.toList()).contains("Foo");

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static lookup map to avoid the exception and return a null, then throw as you'd like:

```
public enum Mammal {
    COW,
    MOUSE,
    OPOSSUM;

    private static Map<String, Mammal> lookup = 
            Arrays.stream(values())
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Enum::name, Function.identity()));

    public static Mammal getByName(String name) {
        return lookup.get(name);
    }
}
```